MudBlazor display list validation
I have a MudForm and want to show a validation error, when no entries are present in the list of the model.
<MudForm>
  <MudGrid Spacing="1" Class="pt-2">
    @foreach (Product product in productList)
    {
      <MudItem xs="4">
        <MudNumericField Label="Amount" @bind-Value="product.Amount" Required="true" />
      </MudItem>
      <MudItem xs="8">
        <MudTextField Label="Titel" @bind-Value="product.title" Required="true" />
      </MudItem>
    }
  </MudGrid>
</MudForm>

In This example I want to display a validation error when productList is empty.
In FluentValidations I have created a rule for it:
RuleFor(parent => parent.productList).NotEmpty();

This works fine for MudBlazor Textfields and also using other rules. The above rule does not get triggered for the list though, probably since the error would not be shown anywhere.
How can I add the validation message properly?
First try was just to add a Mud field to see if it triggers like this:
<MudTextField For="@(() => productList" T="IEnumerable<Product>" />

This does indeed trigger the validator above and shows the error for this text field. But I do not want to add a text field just for a list validation to show.
Second try was using the blazor component ValidationMessage like this:
  <ValidationMessage For="@(() => productList" />'

This causes an exception, it does not work for MudBlazor but needs an EditForm instead. I would rather stay with MudBlazor since the component is already more complex than this example.

Error: System.InvalidOperationException:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.ValidationMessage1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[Product]]
requires a cascading parameter of type EditContext.

How can I add the validation properly using MudBlazor?

I haven't found a MudBlazor component which could do that. But two possible ways to validate the list are:
1. Use a second form inside the form
Use a second form with only a MudTextField validating for the list. Hide the form and bind the errors
<MudForm Model="@model" @ref="@form2" Validation="@(orderValidator.ValidateValue)" @bind-Errors="_errors" Style="visibility: collapse">
    <MudTextField For="@(() => model.ProductList)"/>
</MudForm>


private MudForm form2;
private string[] _errors = { };

Validate both forms in the submit method
private async Task Submit()
{
    await form.Validate();
    await form2.Validate();


    if (form.IsValid && form2.IsValid)
    {
        // submit
    }
}

display the errors
<MudText Color="Color.Error" Typo="Typo.caption">
    @String.Concat(_errors)
</MudText>

MudSnippet: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/camyOUbFezgQerZh
2. Validate the list manually in the submit method
Add a field for the error message
private string _listError = string.Empty;

Validate the list in the submit method
private async Task Submit()
    {
        await form.Validate();
        bool listHasEntries = model.ProductList.Count() > 0;
        _listError = "List is empty";

        if (form.IsValid && listHasEntries)
        {
            // submit
        }
    }

display the errors
@if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_listError))
{
    <MudText Color="Color.Error" Typo="Typo.caption">@_listError</MudText>
}

MudSnippet: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QkcoOAlbIzUTeSFN
Personally I would prefer the first approach since it uses FluentValidation
